# FontAwesome Icon Issue On IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, font-awesome

I have a simple  tag with fontawesome class.

```
<div class="bh-header-menu-ct bh-left">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bh-menu-icon bh-circle bh-color-700 bh-ripple" (click)="onToggle()">
        <i class="fa fa-align-center"></i>
    </a>
</div>

.bh-header-menu-ct{
   height: inherit;
   line-height: 60px;
   padding: 0 10px;
   .bh-menu-icon{
     padding: 10px;
   }
}
```

On IE Its behaving bit wiered

Edit: Code indentation

[image: It appends dash after the icon]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cxyz4ur/2/), but it doesn't behave more weird in IE11 than in other browsers.

Comment: And please add de "bh" classes, without them is impossible to review

Comment: Got the cause...Its was happening when used with <a> tag. With `text-decoration:none` it worked.